# Hide/Remove "Create New" menu in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

i am using creatable select where i want to hide "create new" menu option.  here is my
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-saha-8i0vq) 
 i tried following but no luck
 `promptTextCreator={() => false}`

[image]

thanks you and appreciate any help

Comment: Why are you using Creatable Select if you don't want the creatable option?

Comment: Maybe he wants to be able to create new values by pressing enter instead of clicking on the create new value message.

Comment: @frangaren correct...

Comment: Is any of the answers valid for you? If so mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling create label via `formatCreateLabel={() => undefined}` is the right direction but the menu list sill shows empty space instead of not showing at all which is what you may prefer.

You may want to hide the menu list completely when there is no option by setting the menu list display to `none`

```
  // Remember to define a unique id for your component in the constructor
  // so you can target the right menu list element to hide it
  id = "";
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = "react-select_" + Math.random().toFixed(8).slice(2);
  }

  handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const menuEl = document.querySelector(`#${this.id} [class*="-menu"]`);
      const menuListEl = document.querySelector(
        `#${this.id} [class*="MenuList"]`
      );

      if (
        menuListEl.children.length === 1 &&
        menuListEl.children[0].innerHTML === ""
      ) {
        menuEl.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        menuEl.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  };

...

  <CreatableSelect
        id={this.id}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        formatCreateLabel={() => undefined}
        ...
      />
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit crazy-saha-n9dhe]

Comment: This trick is not elegant and not simple. Have a look into my answer for simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

```
// try this way
return (
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        options={colourOptions}
        noOptionsMessage={() => null}
        // isValidNewOption={() => true}
        // or `isValidNewOption={() => false}`
        promptTextCreator={() => false}
      />
    );
```

Comment: For me `isValidNewOption` and `noOptionsMessage` did the job. :+1:

Comment: @Vaishak how did you use `isValidNewOption`? it's not working for me.

Comment: @Nithur do you have a code snippet (preferably codesandbox) where it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the create new value message at all times while still being able to create new values, you have to use the prop `formatCreateLabel` as follows `formatCreateLabel={() => undefined}` when you define your `CreatableSelect`.

Answer (score 1):

Just treat all the new options as invalid, it will show "No options" message:

```
<CreatableSelect isValidNewOption={() => false}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these props:

`menuIsOpen={false}` and `components={{ DropdownIndicator: null }}`

Then handle `onKeyDown` and `onInputChange` event as explained in => https://react-select.com/creatable, have a look into "Multi-select text input" section

Here is the complete example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

const components = {
  DropdownIndicator: null,
};

const createOption = (label: string) => ({
  label,
  value: label,
});

export default class CreatableInputOnly extends Component<*, State> {
  state = {
    inputValue: '',
    value: [],
  };

  handleChange = (value: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  handleInputChange = (inputValue: string) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
  };

  handleKeyDown = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;

    if (!inputValue) return;

    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Enter':
      case 'Tab':
        this.setState({
          inputValue: '',
          value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)],
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        components={components}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={false}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Type something and press enter..."
        value={value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 <CreatableSelect
  components={{
    ...components,
    Menu: () => null
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to show "Create" option to user but if element exists or any other reason the "Create" option should be hidden.

For exp:

```
        options=[
          {label:"A - 1",value:"A"},
          {label:"B - 1",value:"B"}
          {label:"C - 1",value:"C"}
          {label:"D - 1",value:"D"}
        ]
```

In my case, user can only ***Create A, B, C, D*** but i have formatted their input to make the label ***look as  "A - 1" , "B - 1" and so on***. Now if user again enters ***A, or B or C or D,*** it will not match with ***"A - 1", or "B - 1" or "C - 1" or "D - 1" respectively***, in this case i want to ***hide "Create"*** option because I am already accepting that value but with different format.

So my logic should go as

```
<CreatableSelect
  name="options"
  options={options}
  placeholder="Select or Create"
  isSearchable
  onChange={(option) => appendLabel(option.value)}
  value={null}
  isValidNewOption={(inputValue)=>
  (options.filter((lab)=>lab?.label?.split(" — ") 
 [0].trim().toLowerCase()===inputValue.toLowerCase()).length>0?false:`Create ${inputValue}`}
/>
```